# How to use Magento 2's UI Library Layout LESS variables

Tags: magento2, frontend, less, ui-library

In the Magento 2 UI library there are LESS variables for the layout grid. See [Magento UI Library > Layout](http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/docs/layout.html).

Particullarly there are these two:

```
Variables list names           Default value    Allowable values    Comment
@total-columns                      12        '' | false | value    Number of total columns in layout (i.e. 1, 2, 3)
@layout-column__sidebar-width        2        '' | false | value    Sets sidebar width
```

How does `@total-columns` work, where is it used?  It has a default value of 12.  I have only seen 3 columns in Magento 2, `.column.main`, `.sidebar-main` and `.sidebar-additional`.  I haven't seen any page with 12 columns.

How does `@layout-column__sidebar-width` work, where is it used? It's default value of 2 makes no sense, is it 2px, 2 columns of width.

When you look at these values on the frontend they are percentage measurements:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, so `@total-columns` & `@layout-column__sidebar-width` work by setting the width side bar by dividing one into another.

If you check Luma's compiled style-l.css file, [example](http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css).
You'll find all the main column width changes depending on the number of page layut columns and sidebars have a width of **20.83333333%**.

```
.page-layout-1column .column.main {
  width: 100%;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  order: 2;
}
.page-layout-3columns .column.main {
  width: 58.33333333%;
  display: inline-block;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  order: 2;
}
.page-layout-2columns-left .column.main {
  width: 79.16666667%;
  float: right;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  order: 2;
}
.page-layout-2columns-right .column.main {
  width: 79.16666667%;
  float: left;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  order: 1;
}
.sidebar-main {
  padding-right: 2%;
}
.page-layout-3columns .sidebar-main {
  width: 20.83333333%;
  float: left;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  order: 1;
}
.page-layout-2columns-left .sidebar-main {
  width: 20.83333333%;
  float: left;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  order: 1;
}
.page-layout-2columns-right .sidebar-main {
  width: 20.83333333%;
  float: left;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  order: 1;
}
.page-layout-2columns-right .sidebar-main {
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.sidebar-additional {
  clear: right;
  padding-left: 2%;
}
.page-layout-3columns .sidebar-additional {
  width: 20.83333333%;
  float: right;
  -ms-flex-order: 3;
  -webkit-order: 3;
  order: 3;
}
.page-layout-2columns-left .sidebar-additional {
  width: 20.83333333%;
  float: right;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  order: 2;
}
.page-layout-2columns-right .sidebar-additional {
  width: 20.83333333%;
  float: right;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  order: 2;
}
.page-layout-2columns-left .sidebar-additional {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 2%;
}
```

The width of 20.83333333% is calculated by dividing `@layout-column__sidebar-width` by `@total-columns`.  The main column width is similarly calculated depending on the number of page layut columns.

In Luma the `@total-columns` is set to 24 & `@layout-column__sidebar-width` is set to 5 in:

> app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/web/css/source/_theme.less

```
//
//  Layout grid
//  ---------------------------------------------

@total-columns: 24;

//  Variables for layout columns
@layout-column__sidebar-width: 5;

//  Checkout columns width
@layout-column-checkout__width-left: 6;
```

---

The `.sidebar-main { padding-right: 2%; }` is set with `@layout-column-main__sidebar-offset: 2%;` in:

> app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/web/css/source/_layout.less

---

Also worth noting are the checkout column widths:

```
//  Checkout columns width
@layout-column-checkout__width-left: 3;
@layout-column-checkout__width-main: @layout-column__width - @layout-column-checkout__width-left;
```